# How to validate form again when input value is removed in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, validation

First, I clicked register button without values, my custom directive showed right alert (using sweet alert).

Also there was no problem when I have done same action after filled first input.

But when I filled second input and removed first input,

form validating ignored that first input is whether empty or not.

Here's my fiddle.

[Form Validating Problem](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/pkno7cgo/12/)

and below is my `directive`.

```
.directive('validFocus', function () {
    return {
        required: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            invalidHTML: '&showSwal'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.on('submit', function () {
                var firstInvalid = element[0].querySelector('.ng-invalid');
                if (firstInvalid) {
                    scope.invalidHTML({html: firstInvalid});
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Thank you in advance and fix my foolish please. :)

.

.

UPDATE

Maybe these pictures can make understanding my purpose easy.

**1. Click register button after filled first input**
[image: Click register button after filled first input]

**2. Click rigster button after removed first input value and filled second input**
[image: Click rigster button after removed first input value and filled second input]

.

.

What I expected was 'Enter Name.' not 'Enter Blood Type.' in second picture.

Comment: you can try this https://jsfiddle.net/pkno7cgo/14/ let me know if your issue is resolved or not

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV This works perfect and my problem has solved!! Why did you write comment instead of answer?? I wanna give you +10!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just replace    ng-required="itemForm.name.$invalid" with required.

here is the working code.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <form role="form" ng-submit="registerItem(itemData)" show-swal="showInvalidMsg(html)" name="itemForm" novalidate valid-focus>
            <div>
                <label>Name : </label>
                <input ng-model="itemData.name" required

                       name="name"
                       type="text"
                       placeholder="Enter Name.">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Asset : </label>
                <input ng-model="itemData.asset"
                     required
                       name="asset"
                       type="number"
                       placeholder="Enter Asset.">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Select : </label>
                <select ng-options="sel.key as sel.value for sel in selectList"
                        data-ng-model="selectVal"
            required
             name="some name"
                        data-ng-change="itemData.select=selectVal">                     
                    <option value="">{{addressInfo}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Blood : </label>
                <input ng-model="itemData.blood"
                     required
                       name="blood"
                       type="text"
                       placeholder="Enter Blood Type.">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Color : </label>
                <input ng-model="itemData.color"
                     required
                       name="color"
                       type="text"
                       placeholder="Enter Color.">
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.pageTitle = 'Register New Item';
    $scope.addressInfo = 'Choose One';
    $scope.isUsed = false;
    $scope.selectList = [
        {key: 'one', value: '1'},
        {key: 'two', value: '2'},
        {key: 'three', value: '3'}
    ];
    $scope.showInvalidMsg = function (html) {
        console.log(html);
        $scope.showAlert(
            $scope.pageTitle,
            html.placeholder
        ).then(function () {
            html.focus();
        });
    };
    $scope.registerItem = function (itemData) {

        if ($scope.itemForm.$valid) {
            console.log(itemData);
        }
    };
    $scope.showAlert = function(mTitle, mText){
        return swal({
            title: mTitle,
            text: mText,
            type: 'warning',
            animation: false,
            allowOutsideClick: false
        });
    };
}])
.directive('validFocus', function () {

    return {
        required: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            invalidHTML: '&showSwal'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.on('submit', function () {
                var firstInvalid = element[0].querySelector('.ng-invalid');
                if (firstInvalid) {
                    scope.invalidHTML({html: firstInvalid});
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Fiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/pkno7cgo/14/)

Comment: Perfect for me! Thanks again. :)

Comment: happy to help you